# TCP TSO on nginx very slow transfer 5kb/s on static files - Debian 9

Tags: debian, nginx, debian-stretch

something blocking nginx when requesting a file. Debug log show:

```
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 epoll add event: fd:47 op:3 ev:80002005
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
```

It looks like something wrong with epoll. How to check if it enabled in kernel?
Btw debian deployed on VPS KVM.

full debug log:

```
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Host: dev2.site.com"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Pragma: no-cache"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Cache-Control: no-cache"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.60860567.1557631006; _gid=GA1.2.1680717388.1557631006; _ym_uid=15576310071061036859; _ym_d=1557631007; _ym_isad=2; _ym_visorc_45693372=w"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header done
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52685392
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 rewrite phase: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 using configuration ""
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 rewrite phase: 2
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 post rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 4
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 5
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 access phase: 6
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 access phase: 7
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 post access phase: 8
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 9
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 10
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 11
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 12
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 13
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 14
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http filename: "/var/www/dev2/autobahn.js"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 add cleanup: 000055B0D7128350
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http static fd: 48
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http set discard body
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Date: Sun, 12 May 2019 08:42:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 273615
Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Apr 2019 07:49:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5cbacf12-42ccf"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D711BA90, pos 000055B0D711BA90, size: 256 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:256
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 malloc: 000055B0D7262350:32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D711BA90, pos 000055B0D711BA90, size: 256 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:33024
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 33024 of 33024
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 32768 of 32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 65536
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 32768 of 32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 98304
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 10880 of 32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: -1 of 21888
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 malloc: 000055B0D726A360:32768
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D726A360, 32768, 131072
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D7128468
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7264DD0, size: 21888 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:54656
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: -2 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http finalize request: -2, "/autobahn.js?" a:1, c:1
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 60000:52685396
2019/05/12 15:42:31 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 epoll add event: fd:47 op:3 ev:80002005
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer handler: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7264DD0, size: 21888 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:54656
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 31680 of 54656
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: -1 of 22976
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BD08
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 163840
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726C9A0, size: 22976 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:55744
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BD08
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: -2 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer output filter: -2, "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52685396
2019/05/12 15:42:34 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 60000:52688456
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer handler: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726C9A0, size: 22976 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:55744
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 31680 of 55744
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: -1 of 24064
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D726A360, 32768, 196608
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D7128468
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7264550, size: 24064 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:56832
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: -2 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer output filter: -2, "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52688456
2019/05/12 15:42:36 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 60000:52690304
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer handler: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7264550, size: 24064 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:56832
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 31680 of 56832
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: -1 of 25152
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BD08
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D7262350, 32768, 229376
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D711BC88
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726C120, size: 25152 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:57920
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BD08
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: -2 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer output filter: -2, "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52690304
2019/05/12 15:42:38 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 60000:52692208
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer handler: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726C120, size: 25152 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7262350, size: 32768 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:57920
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 31680 of 57920
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: -1 of 26240
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 read: 48, 000055B0D726A360, 11471, 262144
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 000055B0D7128468
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7263CD0, size: 26240 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 11471 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:1 f:1 s:37711
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 000055B0D711BC98
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: -2 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer output filter: -2, "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52692208
2019/05/12 15:42:40 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 60000:52694856
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http run request: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer handler: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http output filter "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 image filter
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http postpone filter "/autobahn.js?" 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D7262350, pos 000055B0D7263CD0, size: 26240 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055B0D726A360, pos 000055B0D726A360, size: 11471 file: 0, size: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter: l:1 f:1 s:37711
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter limit 0
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 writev: 37711 of 37711
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http write filter 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http copy filter: 0 "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer output filter: 0, "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http writer done: "/autobahn.js?"
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http finalize request: 0, "/autobahn.js?" a:1, c:1
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer del: 47: 52694856
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 set http keepalive handler
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http close request
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http log handler
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 run cleanup: 000055B0D7128350
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 file cleanup: fd:48
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 free: 000055B0D726A360
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 free: 000055B0D7262350
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 free: 000055B0D7127480, unused: 8
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 free: 000055B0D711B5D0, unused: 1970
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 free: 000055B0D71EBAD0
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 hc free: 0000000000000000
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 tcp_nodelay
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 reusable connection: 1
2019/05/12 15:42:43 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 event timer add: 47: 65000:52702580
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http keepalive handler
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 malloc: 000055B0D7115AA0:1024
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 recv: eof:0, avail:1
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 recv: fd:47 582 of 1024
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 reusable connection: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 posix_memalign: 000055B0D7116090:4096 @16
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Host: dev2.site.com"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Pragma: no-cache"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Cache-Control: no-cache"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Referer: http://dev2.site.com/autobahn.js"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header: "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.60860567.1557631006; _gid=GA1.2.1680717388.1557631006; _ym_uid=15576310071061036859; _ym_d=1557631007; _ym_isad=2; _ym_visorc_45693372=w"
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http header done
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 rewrite phase: 0
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 using configuration ""
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 rewrite phase: 2
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 post rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 4
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 5
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 access phase: 6
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 access phase: 7
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 post access phase: 8
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 9
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 generic phase: 10
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 11
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 12
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 13
2019/05/12 15:42:49 [debug] 28971#28971: *15 content phase: 14
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in TSO.

Debian 9 have TSO enabled by default. But it incompatible with NAT routing in ipfw - I have openvpn on this server.

after I do

```
ethtool -K eth0 tso off
```

for save changes after reboot - add this command to /etc/networking/interfaces.

if you have't ethtool - it can be easy install `apt-get install ethtool`

transfer going very fast 10x faster then TSO is on.